# Capybara can't find file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm getting this error when running RSpec:

```
Failures:    

1) Creating a new movie saves the movie and shows the new movie's details
 Failure/Error: attach_file "Poster image", with: "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/interstellar.jpg"

 Capybara::FileNotFound:
   cannot attach file, [:with, "/Users/Ian/code/courses/ruby_on_rails_1/flix-tdd/app/assets/images/interstellar.jpg"]does not exist
```

However, I check and it looks like the file is there:

```
File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/interstellar.jpg")
 => true

File.exist?("/Users/Ian/code/courses/ruby_on_rails_1/flix-tdd/app/assets/images/interstellar.jpg")
 => true
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

```
attach_file "Poster image", "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/interstellar.jpg"
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method

Comment: This is correct - `attach_file` doesn't take a `:with` option